# Using multiple selectors with jquery context menu

Tags: jquery, performance

Is it possible to mention more than one selectors in a jquery context menu,if yes then can anyone show me how to do it.

Thanks

**Edited:**
Following is the code

```
 $.contextMenu({
     selector: '.recur',
     className: 'css-title',
     callback: function (key, options) {
         var vKey = key;
         //var vLinkedId = options.$trigger.attr("linkedid");
         var vLinkedId = $(this).children().children("div:first").attr('linkedid');
         var vmeetingtitle = $(this).children().children("div:first").attr('meetingtitle');
         var vurl = '/SitePages/Send%20Email.aspx?linkedid=' + vLinkedId + '&date=' + $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").val() + "&type=" + vKey;
         var vtitle = vmeetingtitle + ' - ' + vKey + ' email';
         //var Date                  
         OpenDialog(vurl, 600, 300, vtitle);
     },
     items: {
         "Confirmation": {
             name: "Confirmation",
             accesskey: "Confirmation"
         },
             "Catering Cancelled": {
             name: "Catering Cancelled",
             accesskey: "Catering Cancelled"
         },
             "Catering Requirements Amended": {
             name: "Catering Requirements Amended",
             accesskey: "Catering Requirements Amended"
         },
             "Room Changed": {
             name: "Room Changed",
             accesskey: "Room Changed"
         },
             "Time Changed": {
             name: "Time Changed",
             accesskey: "Time Changed"
         },
             "Room and Time Changed": {
             name: "Room and Time Changed",
             accesskey: "Room and Time Changed"
         },
             "Facilities Cancelled": {
             name: "Facilities Cancelled",
             accesskey: "Facilities Cancelled"
         },
             "Facilities Changed": {
             name: "Facilities Changed",
             accesskey: "Facilities Changed"
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

like normal jQuery code, you can use more than one selector like this:

```
selector: '.recur, #theOtherone, .thisClassToo'
```

Comment: yes, it doesn't affect the performance, they are only listeners for the elements.

Comment: an added question, how can I know which selector is being used at a particular click?

Comment: @JCFrane you can do `$(this).attr('class')` to get its classes or `$(this).attr('id')` to get its id